# How to change symfony Mode Using Php?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I want to change symfony mode without running any command line. It is possible if I use some php code and a button to change symfony mode automatically for anyone.
Please Help.

And i don't want try with below command:

```
$ sudo chown master-chef -R /var/www/Symfony2/app/cache/prod
```

Comment: You should use the same user for cli and the web server.

Comment: can i get some php code to do manually ?